# C# static class and data members question

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, static-methods, static-members

I am not sure how to implement what I have in mind using C# .Net 3.5. I have a static class called Common which contains common methods. One of the method is PrepareReportParameters. This method accepts a string ReportParams and parse it to get the parameter values. I load this ReportParams string into a Dictionary . And then verify whether the required elements exist. I check that like:

```
if (ReportParamList.ContainsKey("PAccount"))
{
    ReportParamList.TryGetValue("PAccount", out PrimaryAccount);
}
```

where PrimaryAccount is a static variable in my Common class. And I can access this elsewhere as Common.PrimaryAccount.

Though, this approcah of accessing the report parameters will work but I want PrimaryAccount to be accessed as `Common.ReportParameters.PrimaryAccount`. 
Here is the problem, I don't know what type ReportParameters should be and how can I have all the report parameters added to this type? How should I define ReportParameters? Does it sound feasible or it doesn't make any sense. Please H E L P!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're basically used to using global variables to pass around state. That's generally a really bad idea.

Why doesn't your method just *return* the primary account value? That can then be passed to other things which need it.

If you find yourself with a lot of static members - and in particular if other classes are fetching mutable static variables - consider whether there's a more OO design you could apply. It'll be easier to understand, easier to test, and easier to maintain.

EDIT: Okay, so currently you have:

```
public static class Common
{
    public static int PrimaryAccount;
    // other static fields

    public static void PrepareReportParameters(string reportParameters)
    {
        // Code to set the fields
    }
}
```

Instead of that, use a normal class:

```
public class ReportParameters
{
    public int PrimaryAccount { get; private set; }
    // Other properties

    private ReportParameters(int primaryAccount, ....)
    {
        this.PrimaryAccount = primaryAccount;
    }

    // Could use a constructor instead, but I prefer methods when they're going to
    // do work
    public static ReportParameters Parse(string report)
    {
        // Parse the parameter, save values into local variables, then
        return new ReportParameters(primaryAccount, ...);
    }
}
```

Then call this from the rest of your code, and pass the `ReportParameters` reference to anything that needs it.

Comment: Jon, I added that method to static class so that I can use it from all other applications where I need to parse report params. That method basically parse the ReportParams that has more than one parameter that I would need in my applications. So it can't just return primary account value. Yes, I had to create lot of static members that I want to avoid.

Comment: @user465876: So create a data structure to encapsulate everything that you parse, and return that. Look at what you've got as static members, and make them *instance* members in a new type.

Comment: :( LOST! an example would really help.

Comment: @user465876: I've given a brief example now.

Comment: Hmm, only issue I feel is that I need to maintain two classes ReportParameters and my original Common class that has rest of the common code. What is your take on "Nashwan" solution below where In my application I still be using only one - Common class?

Comment: @user465876: Nashwan's answer is still suggesting creating another class, but including a static field which retains a reference to an instance of it. Personally I'd avoid that, for the reasons given in my answer - static state makes it hard to reason about and test code.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the sample code and the explanation. It really helped. By the way, I have more that 10 report parameters and passing it to the private constructor can be simplified or it is ok?

Comment: @user465876: You *could* just have an empty private parameterless constructor, and set them via an object initializer: `return new ReportParameter { PrimaryAccount = ..., SecondProperty = ... };`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class called ReportParameters with the relevant strongly-typed properties, and give Common a static instance of it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best design.  Theres a certain amount of 'code smell' to having Common.PrimaryAccount only to be allowed to be accessed after PrepareReportParameters is called.  Maybe you'd consider an instance class, passing in the parameters in the constructor?